# AKPickerView - (OSStatus error -600.)

Tags: swift

I am trying to create a horizontal picker view using `AKPickerView library`.
I imported AKPickerView library as a pod file, I created the bridging header and did all the set up correctly. However, I get 
`The operation couldn’t be completed - OSStatus error -600` when I try to run the project. Can you tell me what I am doing wrong. Thanks for your help.

```
import UIKit
import AKPickerView

class ViewController: UIViewController, AKPickerViewDelegate,    AKPickerViewDataSource {

var myArray = ["one","two","three"]
@IBOutlet var pickerView: AKPickerView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.pickerView = AKPickerView(frame: CGRect.zero)
    self.pickerView.delegate = self
    self.pickerView.dataSource = self
}


func numberOfItemsInPickerView(pickerView: AKPickerView!) -> UInt {

return UInt(self.myArray.count)
}


func pickerView(pickerView: AKPickerView!, titleForItem item: Int) -> String!{
    return self.myArray[item]

}


func pickerView(pickerView: AKPickerView, didSelectItem item: Int) {

    // no set up yet
}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just quit your iOS Simulator then reopen the simulator then build your source Now it will work.